# ArcGIS Collector doesn't show up in iTunes-cannot transfer tile package

Tags: arcgis-collector, tile-package

I am trying to use tile package offline in Collector. I have followed the instructions in the link below. My issue is: Collector never shows up under Apps in the iTunes, so I can't use it to transfer my tile package to my iPad.

I have updated iOS, all my apps, everything I can think of. I am using iTunes 12.8 on Windows 7. I'm not sure which iPad I have but it's pretty new as of this post.

Do I have to have Collector downloaded as an app to my computer?

I want to just take the tile package from ArcMap and load it to my iPad.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ios/collect-data/offline-use.htm

[image]

Comment: When you connect your iPad to your computer are you prompted to Trust or Not Trust your computer?

Comment: @MapsyDaisy yes I was and I chose "Trust this computer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was shared libraries were checked. I am not sure if this was due to my organization's security policy or if this applies to everyone with the same problem, but this is how I fixed it.

Open iTunes

Select Edit on the Menu Bar

Select Preferences

Select the Restrictions Tab

Select the lock at the bottom left corner

Uncheck Shared Libraries

Select OK

Close and Reopen iTunes